# how show MSG php joomla

Tags: php, joomla

my php code is

```
F0FTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/tables');
    $orderpayment = F0FTable::getInstance('Order', 'J2StoreTable');
    $orderpayment->load($data['custom']);
    $orderpayment->add_history('NUmfactor : '.$data['custom']);
    $orderpayment->add_history('Banck : '.$_POST['SaleReferenceId']);
    $orderpayment->add_history('Track : '.$data['order_id']);
    $orderpayment->transaction_details  = $data[''];
    $orderpayment->transaction_id       = $_POST['SaleReferenceId'];
    $orderpayment->transaction_status   = $data['payment_status'];
```

how show MSG ?

```
$msg = ($orderpayment);
                    $msg .= '<br /> NUmfactor  : ' . $data['custom'];
                    $msg .= '<br /> Banck : ' . $_POST['SaleReferenceId'];
                    $msg .= '<br /> Track : ' . $data['order_id'];
```

how show MSG ? ??????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

To echo message in output, one method is that redirect user to the current page with Joomla API like this :

```
$status="Notice";
$url="index.php";

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->enqueueMessage($msg, $status);
$app->redirect(JRoute::_($url));
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices